# Prime-square or prime-squared?

Tags: orthography

I am not so sure which one is the correct spelling. When we try to say a square/cube of a prime, we should call it a "prime-squared/cubed" or a "prime-square/cube" number?

It sounds to me that "prime-squared/cubed" is the right choice as we are squaring/cubing the number. But I found both versions in different webpages, so I get confused. Are they both acceptable or it was a typo?

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: MathsSE.

Answer (score 0):

In the expression "a prime-square", the hyphenated word is a *noun*, whereas in "a prime-squared number" the hyphenated word is an *adjective*. Both are correct in the context they're being used for.

Thus it would be correct to say:

> A *prime-square* is also called a *prime-squared number* and refers to a prime number that has been squared. Similarly, a prime that has been cubed is a *prime-cube*.

However, the above is an example of correct grammar rather than preferred usage. The terms themselves don't seem to be very common: Google Ngram Viewer returned a null result for each of the hyphenated forms. A broader search through Google Books shows [mixed results](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=5g_eXJnyNMrpvgTvt6TIBA&q=%22prime+squared%22&oq=%22prime+squared%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...21162.21162.0.22993.1.1.0.0.0.0.156.156.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.XN1A9NglBv8), but it seems that the unhyphenated expressions are also used: [this book](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=07PZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22prime-squared%22&dq=%22prime-squared%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGk8CKt6HiAhUKrI8KHdkMDdYQ6AEIUDAH) uses both *prime squared* and *a prime squared number*.

Answer (score 0):

The most common expression is neither of these but *the square of a prime*. [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prime+square%2Cprime+squared%2Cthe+square+of+a+prime%2C+square+of+a+prime&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprime%20square%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprime%20squared%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20square%20of%20a%20prime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csquare%20of%20a%20prime%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cprime%20square%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprime%20squared%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20square%20of%20a%20prime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csquare%20of%20a%20prime%3B%2Cc0).

In fact, the Google Ngram overestimates the use of *prime square* for this concept because most of the hits use *prime square* for something else.

Answer (score 0):

In the noun "prime-squared", the word "prime" acts as a noun (it is shorthand for "prime number"). It would be my preferred choice by far, referring to a "prime number that has been squared". I would argue that the second formulation is actually wrong and should be avoided! Indeed, as a "prime" is a noun referring to a "prime-number", a "prime-square" seems, in this context, to refer to a "prime-square number", i.e. a number which is both a prime and a square (which obviously cannot exist).

Answer (score -1):

In fact, such terms are commonly used in mathematical society. And that is why I am asking this question. I just searched through MathSciNet (you might have no access) and it seems that native English speakers all used "prime-squared" and other people use both. (See a screenshot as follows) So I guess "prime-squared" should be more appropriate?[image]